# WP 8.1 Hub SectionsInViewChanged not firing for two sections

Tags: events, win-universal-app

I have a hub control with two sections.  I want to fire an event when the main section in view changes.  In order to do that I use the SectionsInViewChanged event.  However this does not fire when the user swipes to the next section (when there are only 2).  When I add another section then it fires?  Is there a different event which I should use?

Answer (score 0):

MSFT recommends not to use Hub control with only two sections.

> Tip: Two section Hubs don’t wrap. This is by design. Having a Hub with
>   fewer than three sections is not recommended UX and supporting
>   wrapping for two section Hubs was very expensive.

http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/07/22/tips-and-tricks-for-using-xaml-controls-in-your-universal-windows-apps/